# Reference for converting UTF8 in a MySql DB

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Wonder if anyone can help.

I recently had an issue with UTF8 in the Database and pages of a bespoke CMS I inherited. Going forward that's all sorted now, the code and DB has been changed to cater and properly convert, however I have an issue in that existing entries in the DB are obvioulsy sat there in the old character format and I need to convert all those.

Eg Ä¶, Ä«

I was going to run an replace in the mysql DB to replace all these, but what I could do with is knowing what all these weird characters translate to eg ó.

Can anyone recommend a good table/reference to look at ? I have been searching but can't seem to come up with the right thing.

If I understand right these are two byte UTF8 characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running these values in [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php).

It looks like they've been valid, then [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)'d.

If that's the case, try running a loop and update these rows.

Comment: Hi, Thanks - I gave this a quick try on the actual page and it works - I'll figure out the easiest way of updating the DB now, there's about 30 tables it seems!